# A little help with firebug and jQuery!

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I have a div element that when I click on it on IE, it shows me a clue tip. But, when I click in Firefox (or Chrome), this tip doesn't shów at all.

I have firebug installed but I dont't have good experience on using it.

With firebug, can I know why this tip isn't showing?? How can I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you want more help with this (not necessarily in relation to firebug) you might want to post a code example or a link in a new question.

Comment: Please don't repeat punctuation or use exclamation points in your question title. This isn't eBay or Craigslist. If everyone abuses punctuation to draw more attention to their question, we'll just end up with every question being written in caps trailed by 20 exclamation points.

Comment: Your gonna have to post some code if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Firebug icon at the bottom right of your browser window. A window pane should come up at the bottom of the screen with something like this:

```
Console panel is disabled

Use this page to enable or disable following panels. Enabling these panels will reduce performance and will cause a page reload.
    Console     Support for Console logging.          Disabled Always
    Script      Support for JavaScript debugging.     Disabled Always
    Net         Support for Network monitoring.       Disabled Always
```

Check all 3 boxes and click "Apply for http://www.example.org"

Check whatever errors come up when you click on the DIV.

Comment: Nothing appears on console... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript error console after clicking on the div in firefox.

> Tools > Error console

This should give you the line of code causing your error and a description of the error.

Comment: I put an alert that opens when this div is clicked. It works on IE, but FF doesn't show nothing. I've tried to insert a breakpoint, but nothing happens.

Comment: It's probably due to a page error that happened before clicking on the div, and hence it does not run the future javascript.  Please check the error console I mentioned above from the tools menu, and click on errors to see what the previous errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code looks like `<div alt="text">`. The alt attribute is to be used when something can't be displayed. "For user agents that cannot display images, forms, or applets, this attribute specifies alternate text." [W3C HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.8)

Use the title attribute to get your desired result on IE/Firefox/Chrome `<div title="text">`. "Values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers frequently display the title as a "tool tip"..." [WC3 HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3)

For even more info read http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200412/the_alt_and_title_attributes/